# spellcheck using solr and hybris

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, spell-checking

I am using solr 7.7.2 with hybris 6.7. I am trying to get correct spell check for misspelled words. I am able to achieve it to some extent but it is not working for certain cases. For eg. while searching for **apple wath**, I am getting **apple with** as spell check and not **apple watch**. One of the reason behind this is that the name attribute in my database contains both 'apple watch' and 'apple with'.
Some other examples
misspelled word - suggestion that I am getting
suop - shop (it should be 'suop')
Aple watch - apple water (it should be 'apple watch')
Samsung note 10 lite - Samsung note 10 litre

solrconfig.xml

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
<str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_spell</str>
<lst name="spellchecker">
<str name="name">en</str>
<str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
<str name="field">spellcheck_en</str>
<str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
<float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
<int name="maxEdits">2</int>
<int name="minPrefix">0</int>
<int name="maxInspections">5</int>
<int name="minQueryLength">2</int>
</lst>
</searchComponent>
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
<int name="rows">10</int>
<str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
<str name="df">fulltext</str>
</lst>
<arr name="last-components">
<str>spellcheck</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>
```

schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text_spell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
<filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
<filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
<filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I tried many other configurations including collate but the issue persists mostly for multiword searches.

Comment: Why synonyms filter is added only at query time only and not at indexing?

Comment: Is it going to affect spellcheck in any way? I needed those synonyms only while querying. That why.

Comment: you can check the same field type in the analysis page...how it is working for you..

Comment: I have checked that. Synonym is not creating any issue with spellcheck.